# Using Regex to replace username with links

Tags: php, regex, string

I'm using the Twitter API to fetch information about all of my followers. In many cases, their bio will have a link to their Instagram page. They usually define it by writing something along the lines of `IG: myigusername94` or `instagram - myigusername93`. I'm not that good with regex and I'd like to know how to test for the presence of a set of chars like `ig:` or 'instagram -` and replace it with

```
"ig: <a href="http://instagram.com/myigusername94">myigusername94</a>"
```

I know this is probably a simple fix. But, I'm very new to regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search using this regex:

```
\b(instagram|ig)\s*[:-]\s*\K([\w.]+)\b
```

And replace it by:

```
<a href="$1">$1</a>
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cA0oF9/1)

#### Code:

```
$re = '/\b(instagram|ig)\s*[:-]\s*\K([\w.]+)\b/'; 

$result = preg_replace($re, '<a href="$1">$1</a>', $input);
```